# Java threading - How to properly wait for threads to finish?

Tags: java, multithreading

I had a test at university telling me to fix the code below, so it waits for the threads to finish
before printing "END". content of MyThread was unknown:

```
Thread s1 = new MyThread();
Thread s2 = new MyThread();
s1.start();
s2.start();
s1.sleep(1000);
s2.sleep(1000);
System.out.println("END");
```

My solution at first was to join() the 2 threads, however that did not work.

```
Thread s1 = new MyThread();
Thread s2 = new MyThread();
s1.start();
s2.start();
s1.sleep(1000);
s2.sleep(1000);
s1.join();
s2.join();
System.out.println("END");
```

Then I tried checking if the Threads were alive with a while loop.

```
Thread s1 = new MyThread();
Thread s2 = new MyThread();
s1.start();
s2.start();
s1.sleep(1000);
s2.sleep(1000);
while(s1.IsAlive() || s2.IsAlive){
  continue;
}
System.out.println("END");
```

But this one did not work either. Apperantly the correct answer was to join the threads AND remove the 2 sleeps:

```
Thread s1 = new MyThread();
Thread s2 = new MyThread();
s1.start();
s2.start();
s1.join();
s2.join();
System.out.println("END");
```

My question is: Why are none of my answers acceptable?
Asked my lab leader, but he could not give me an answer. Coded the test out at home and it seems to work just fine.
Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Works fine for me both with and without sleep. I would suspect it is something JVM specific. Do you know the JVM versions where you tested it?

Comment: What do you mean by "did not work"? Do you realise that `t.sleep()` does not necessarily make `t` go to sleep, but makes the current thread go to sleep instead? You should really always call `sleep` in the form `Thread.sleep()` to avoid confusion.

Comment: @Sweeper By "did not work" I mean that our scuffed website did no accept it. And no, I did not know that, thanks for clarifying! However, I did not put those sleep calls in the code, that's how the test came by default and all it said was that the code runs fine, but reaches the end before both Threads are completed, therefore I did not even give it a second thought, just assumed I need to add the the join()s. Thank you again for clarifying!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imagine a future scenario: you now work in a bank or worse yet a nuclear power station. The importance of knowing precisely when those background tasks are completed is much higher.

Note that sleep is a static method so should not be referenced via instance `s1` or `s2` - the sleep affects the current thread only.

The solutions that use `Thread.sleep(x)` may appear to work if the task is short lived, but a sleep gives no guarantee that the operations were completed. What if each MyThread takes 1 millisecond and your code is called a million times? Using `sleep(1000)` means that your program will run for an excessively long time without knowing the transactions definitely ended.

The solution with `while(s1.IsAlive()...` may appear to work but is a fail because your calling thread is running a tight loop. It will be consuming excessive CPU because it is always running while others task are, and therefore that is at the detriment of the CPU allocated for MyThread tasks.

The correct answer uses `Thread.join`. Your calling thread blocks - no CPU wasted - until each MyThread ends. The elapsed time is exactly matched to their running time, and you know the MyThreads were ended.

Comment: Thank you for explaining! Gonna be honest I did not expect that I was supposed to delete lines from the original question to make my code perfect, especially since this is a beginner Java class.

Comment: Nice for a beginner Java Class @VrbovszkiBence

Answer (score 1):

The solution with `join()` is for sure correct.
If we look at the [official docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.html#join(long)) we can see the following ...

> public final void join​(long millis) throws InterruptedException
> Waits at most millis milliseconds for this thread to die. A timeout of 0 means to wait forever.
> This implementation uses a loop of this.wait calls conditioned on this.isAlive. As a thread terminates the this.notifyAll method is invoked. It is recommended that applications not use wait, notify, or notifyAll on Thread instance

This method was designed precisely to handle this use case.

The reason why you might not be getting the expected results is because of the `t.sleep()` calls you call on a reference to another thread, see one of the comments to the original post.